# How to workaround certain differences between PhantomJSDriver and ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

I have an issue when switching from `ChromeDriver` to `PhantomJSWebDriver`, that I need a workaround for.

Using the ChromeDriver I perform a `.Click` on a visible element, with another visible element next to it. the `.Click` makes the web page place a 'popup' over these elements. I then perform a `.Click` on an element within this 'popup' and it then goes away, and I am able to perform a `.Click` on the second of the original elements and it all works fine.

However, when I switch to using the `PhantomJSDriver` it complains that the second element is NOT visible after the 'popup' has been removed, and so wont do the `.Click`.

Is this a known issue with the PhantomJS driver, or is there some way to get it to 're-evaluate' what is visible? I have tried using a `DriverWait` looking for the element and waiting for it to be 'Displayed' but that doesn't work

```
WebDriverWait waitforpopdown = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
waitforpopdown.Until(d => {
    var elpd = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName(trid));
    return elpd.Displayed;
});
```

I'm using PhantomJS 2.1.1 and Selenium 2.52.0.0 and using C#

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with PhantomJSDriver. It hasn't the same javascript engine than Chrome, FF and IE.

I "fixed" my problem by installing a selenium server that is running chrome on a docker. If you have the ability to do that, I would recommend to work that way. It's an actual chrome browser that is running, so you don't have any difference between your different types of chromes.

You can find information about it on the following page : https://github.com/peroumal1/docker-chrome-selenium

EDIT : You have to declare your driver like this (note that it's java Syntax, but I'm sure you'll be able to find the C# syntax) :

```
return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://myurl.url:8888"), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds like it may be the way to go

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, can you mark it as correct ? Thanks